# array not sorting on device - works in Simulator

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray

I've been trying to fix this but I haven't been able to do it so far... in my device my array isn't shown ordered, while on the Simulator it is...

in these lines I sort / assign / reload my view.

```
self.appDelegate.listaEventos = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *first = ((EventoModelo*)a).fecha ;
    NSDate *second = ((EventoModelo*)b).fecha;
    NSComparisonResult result =  [first compare:second];
    return result;
}];
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Any tips on what I can do? Device is running iOS 8.3, deployment target for my project is 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resulted to be in the locale of my iOS device & a different one being used the simulator... One was the same as the locale used while generating the JSON from which dates where read, the other one wasn't - resulting in dates being NULL thus not sorting correctly...